# Setup Wordpress with Magento using Nginx

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

I have a Magento 2 installed in /var/www/html/ folder using mydomain.com and I added a Wordpress in /var/www/html/pub/wp/ folder using mydomain.com/wp/
When I tried to access mydomain.com/wp/readme.html it's working fine but all php files are not accessible so I can't connect to admin mydomain.com/wp/wp-login.php and see my Wordpress.

I added this to my nginx configuration but it's not working :

```
location /wp/ {
  index index.html index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /wp/index.php?q=$uri&args;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  /wp/index.php;
    include        fastcgi.conf;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have installed WordPress at pub/wp but your Nginx config refers just to /wp/. Either modify your Nginx config to refer to /pub/wp/ or move WordPress to the root (eg. /wp/).

https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/nginx/

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server  127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  # Magento 2 base URL
  server_name m2.latest.composer.fp.com;

  # Magento 2 root directory
  set $MAGE_ROOT /home/magento2/html;

  set $MAGE_DEBUG_SHOW_ARGS 1;

  include /home/magento2/html/nginx.conf.sample;

  # WordPress is installed in pub/wp
  location /wp/ {
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wp/index.php?q=$uri&args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index  /wp/index.php;
      include        fastcgi.conf;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but yes I moved the Wordpress but I'm having the same issue

Comment: That config worked fine for me in my testing. I've updated my answer with my full Nginx config.

Answer (score 0):

My magento project installed on docker.
My WP site installed in pub/wp/.
When installing i used this documentation https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/docs/

I faced with the same problem.

I resolve this problem by changing fastcgi_pass value to the value what is used in my docker container (fastcgi_backend):

```
location /wp/ {
index index.html index.php;
try_files $uri $uri/ /wp/index.php$is_args$args;
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_index  /wp/index.php;
    include        fastcgi.conf;
}
```

After that you need to change siteurl and home value in wp_options table

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but turned out it was due to Varnish. If anyone else has the same issues, try this:

Add this to above your server block in nginx config

```
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $https_flag {
    default off;
    https on;
}

server {
    listen 8080; .....
```

Then add this to your magento nginx.conf file located in your Magento Install (I added it after the "# PHP entry point for main application" block)... like this

```
# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

location /wp/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS $https_flag;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```